# Omit GCP VMs without specific label, assign different value instead

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ansible, jinja2

I have the following GCP inventory source configured:

```yaml
---
plugin: google.cloud.gcp_compute
projects:
  - project1
  - project2
  - project3
filters:
  #- status = RUNNING
  #- scheduling.automaticRestart = true AND status = RUNNING
keyed_groups:
  # Create groups from GCE labels
  - prefix: gcp
    key: labels
  - prefix: gcp_project
    key: project
hostnames:
  # List host by name instead of the default public ip
  - name
compose: 
  ansible_host: name ~ "." ~ labels.domainmembership ~ ".local"
```

Which gives the following value for `ansible_host` when a VM named `server1` has a `domainmembership` label with the value `domain1`:

```yaml
ansible_host: "server1.domain1.local"
```

How would I use `omit` to set `ansible_host` to `networkInterfaces[0].networkIP` if `labels.domainmembership` is empty or not present?

Answer (score 1):

*Disclaimer: I don't have a GCP account at hand to test this.*

---

[`omit`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_filters.html#making-variables-optional) is not what you are looking for here, as it will make the `ansible_host` variable optional, so, in short, `ansible_host` could be undefined.

What you really want is to offer a [`default`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#jinja-filters.default), and since you want to default also when the value is defined but empty, you want to set its second parameter to `true`.

So, this should do:

```yaml
compose: 
  ansible_host: >-
    name ~ "." ~ labels.domainmembership ~ ".local" 
      | default(networkInterfaces[0].networkIP, true)
```